# Phone acceleration to image scaling

Tags: android, image, android-sensors

I'm building a solution in which there is an image shown on the app and if the phone is pulled closer to the user, the image zooms-in and if its pushed away, the image zooms-out.

I tried using a lot of acceleration detector apps to understand the values. I could see that the movement is pretty much on z axis.

Now I'm stuck at building a scale factor (to zoom in or zoom out image) from this acceleration value. Please help.